# Modify PCB Mains Voltage input to 12VDC

Tags: batteries, pcb, mains, 12v, heatsink

One of my amplifiers has died so I need to find out if I can hookup a spare I have lying around as per "Section B" of the below block diagram.

I have done the same modification before on simpler circuits but the circuit I have on hand is far more complex in design than those I have worked on, and ideally would not like the smoke to escape from it.

Basically, I want to replace the input transformer of "Section A" with a direct 12V source like a battery. I would solder the transformer secondaris to +12V and the Heatsink to 0V (GND). Would this work?

Please also advise if I want to completely remove high voltage potential from the circuit, would I be correct in assuming I have to remove the DC transformer alltogether to avoid backfeeding it with 12V at the secondary or is there nothing to worry about. I measure 320VDC at its primary when connected to the mains. The ciruit will still be isolated in a project box for asthetics and saftey.

[image]

Comment: what's a DC transformer?

Comment: Jsotola, not sure but it looks something like this: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32495030305.html

Comment: That's a SMPS or switch-mode-power-supply transformer, specifically designed to work at frequencies above 50/60Hz. Jsotola was hinting that *no* transformers run on DC, so no, you can't "backfeed" it with DC. Bottom line is, if the power supply is only generating 12.00vDC, then replacing it with a 12.00vDC battery should work. Provided a) the battery is 12.00v (or the circuit can tolerate 14.5v-10.0v), and b) there is no "power good" indicator going to the rest of the circuitry.

Comment: It's likely that your amp relies on having two separate secondaries on the transformer to produce something like 15-0-15 VDC, in which case you'll need two separate and isolated 15V supplies. One 12V battery alone won't work.

Comment: rdtsc, I see. So just to expand abit, irrespective of where on the circuit board I solder a power connector, so long as that point is common throughout the circuit, nothing should go pop. I ask specifically because I am planning on attaching the ground terminal directly to the heatsink as there is more surface area there compared to other points on the board. So in this case the return/entry path to/from the source (battery) will be the transistors?

Comment: Finbarr. You could be correct, but I might have to chance it since all 4 secondary terminals feeding the PCB seem to be connected according to the continuity test I ran.

Comment: Finbarr. After a little digging I found the part number for the output stage and you are indeed correct. It uses the TDA2030 which expects -Vs and +Vs as you mentioned. Guess some modifications are best left alone. If I had enough rep to upvote everyone who chipped in with some advice I would, but alas I am new here. Thanks anyway and I look forward to everyones help with my next experiment.

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to confirm the output voltages of whatever the existing power supply. If it only outputs a single 12V supply, then you can connect a 12V battery to the output of the power supply section. But remember, typical lead acid batteries can be charged up to 14.4V and your amplifier should be able to withstand that. Also, it would be better if you connect the negative wire to the PCB instead of the heat sink.

Anyway, more information can be given if you provide a schematic or a model number of you amplifier.

Comment: Thanks for the information Arosha. It would have been applicable but unfortunatly I found the part number used in the circuit and it expects a dual supply, so my mod wont work.